# Three.js - Margin mesh object inside the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I margin a mesh object inside a scene? Here is the code

```
function initMesh(x, y, z) {
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('pleura.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh.scale.x = x;
    mesh.scale.y = y;
    mesh.scale.z = z;
    mesh.opacity=1;
    mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    scene.add(mesh);
});}
```

This loads the mesh in the center of the scene.

Thanks!